# Does Google's GData Picasa API and OAuth work using C#?

Tags: c#, oauth, gdata

Does Google's GData Picasa  API and OAuth work using C#?  If so, can someone post how to set the OAuthToken and then make calls using the PicasaService?   I am able to get all the way to creating an oauth_token but cannot figure out how to set this value in the GData API and succesfully make calls.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, the GData API is a REST-ful XML/JSON based mechanism... there is a [C# client library](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html) for GData, but if the client library doesn't support a particular feature, there is  no reason that you couldn't manually construct the HTTP queries necessary to perform an operation that is supported by GData but not the client library.